# Can the C# JITter optimize repeated delegate calls?

Tags: c#, .net, delegates, jit

In my current codebase, complex `if` statements are often replaced with delegate calls. Because of the structure of the code, the same delegate will be called many times over the course of the application. For example,

```
class ExampleClass
{
    private delegate double ExampleDelegate(double x, double y);
    private ExampleDelegate _exampleMethod;
    private bool _condition1;

    ...

    public double ApiFunction(List<double> a, List<double> b, bool condition2)
    {
        if ((_condition1 && !condition2) || getCondition3())
        {
            _exampleMethod = adder;
        }
        else
        {
            _exampleMethod = subtracter;
        }

        double finalResult = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < a.Count; i++)
        {
            finalResult += _exampleMethod(a[i], b[i]);
        }

        return finalResult;
    }

    private double adder(double a, double b)
    {
        return a + b;
    }

    private double subtracter(double a, double b)
    {
        return a - b;
    }
}
```

Since performance is a concern here, I'm wondering if the JITter will eventually realize that one of these methods is being called every time and inline or otherwise optimize the call.

So, **can the C# JITter inline or otherwise optimize repeated delegate calls**?

Comment: How about you benchmark it to see what kind of overheard your delegate-based dispatch has? Also, afaik using Method Groups is more expensive than using lambda expressions, so I'd suggest trying `_exampleMethod = (a, b) => adder(a, b);`. But again, you're curious about perf? Benchmark!

Comment: @MarcinJuraszek As far as your remark about lambdas, the actual methods are much more complicated, usually around 25 lines. I may do some performance benchmarking to see the actual performance impact later, but I'm also interested in what technically happens behind the scenes, not just the actual performance impact. Thanks.

Comment: @MarcinJuraszek Why do you think that creating a new method that does nothing but call another method, passing along exactly the same parameters, and doing no productive work would be more efficient?

Comment: @HansPassant Excellent info. Would you consider making this an answer? It essentially does answer my question.

Comment: @Servy it's because of delegate caching. See http://vibrantcode.com/2013/02/19/lambdas-vs-method-groups/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It does not.  Delegate calls are always indirect calls and dynamically bound at runtime.  This happens at the time the call is made, only then is the value of the delegate object known.  The jitter runs before that, there is nothing the optimizer can do to improve them, it has no knowledge whatsoever what exactly is going to be called.

Note how it can't know whether the target method is an instance method or static, it assumes an instance method.  Extra work needs to be done by the call stub if it is static to rejigger the call stack.  That extra work is more substantial for x64 code.  Notable in the snippet is that a static method would normally make more sense so beware of this.

First call is expensive, that's when the call stub is created and the target method needs to be jitted.  Since in this case the jitter will already have correctly guessed at what the method looks like, the stub is simply a single JMP instruction.  Any call after this runs at normal speed and, beyond the JMP, will not be substantially slower than a normal call, albeit that you can't benefit from inlining like these small methods normally would.  No changes are made, .NET does not have anything like a hotspot compiler since it doesn't use an interpreter.

You'll have to measure, beware that this is very fast code so simple benchmark mistakes tend to hurt and measurements won't be very consistent.  But consider spending time on it only when you discover you have an actual perf problem. That is not common, delegates don't suck.